# Cannot find module ‘@expo/metro-config’ when trying to start the project with expo cli >= 4.8.0

Tags: react-native, expo

I recently tried to launch my project on a new computer. I downloaded the source code from its repository and ran npm install to get all the needed packages.

However, when I run `npm start` or `expo start:web`, I get the error:
`Cannot find module '@expo/metro-config'`

I ran `npm install @expo/metro-config` and the install run without issue, but I still get the “Cannot find module '@expo/metro-config'” error.
The only post I saw regarding this error recommends editing the `metro.config.js` but I do not use one.

I am on SDK 42, and the project launches fine on my other computer. Any idea what is happening?

FYI, I use to perform this whole operation without any issue until now.

**UPDATE:**

I ran `npm install -g @expo/metro-config` and now I get the error `Cannot find module 'resolve-from'`

So it looks like maybe running `npm install -g expo-cli` doesn't actually install all the necessary packages? Could it be the issue?

I managed to make it "work" (get other missing packages errors down the line) by reverting to expo-cli 4.7.3. Anything from 4.8.0 and above will cause the error.

Something else is that on a fresh npm install, after running `npm install -g expo-cli`, if I try to create a project with `expo init`, I will get the error `Error: Cannot find module 'kleur'`. Running `npm install kleur` fix it, but maybe that's also a clue.

Comment: hi there! can you try this on a new project? `expo init` and then choose a blank project and run `expo start:web` on it. do you see the same issue? also, are you using the latest version of expo-cli?

Comment: Hi @brentvatne. I just updated `expo-cli` and created a new blank project. I am seeing the same error on the brand new project.

Comment: hope the instructor here help you: https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/

Comment: also, try to create a new project with `npx install-expo-modules` instead of `expo init`

Comment: @novonimo  `npx install-expo-modules` gives me the error `Uncaught Error AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Project file "MainApplication" does not exist in android project for root "C:\testproject"`